# Using Webpack's multi-compiler feature breaks Express, 'window is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm using Webpack to build a client+server Node.js/Express app. I'm using the multi-compiler feature to build both app.js (server) and main.js (client). If I build app.js by itself, Express runs fine. If I use the multi-compiler feature to build both, it fails because of this error:

```
user@mac:~/project$ node build/app.js 

/project/build/app.js:132611
module.exports = typeof self == 'object' ? self.FormData : window.FormData;
                                                               ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/project/build/app.js:132611:61)
at __webpack_require__ (/project/build/app.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/project/build/app.js:114314:17)
at __webpack_require__ (/project/build/app.js:20:30)
at Object.hasOwn (/project/build/app.js:112065:20)
at __webpack_require__ (/project/build/app.js:20:30)
at Object.VERSION (/project/build/app.js:24863:17)
at __webpack_require__ (/project/build/app.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/project/build/app.js:59:11)
at __webpack_require__ (/project/build/app.js:20:30)
```

I'm basing my webpack configs off this: https://github.com/villeristi/vue.js-starter-template

And you can find my modified webpack files here:

Base webpack config: http://pastebin.com/zeEEbNrf

Dev webpack config: http://pastebin.com/p5isXwSd (imports the above as webpackBase)

When I diff the built app.js files built by itself and with multi-compiler, the code is massively different, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

What can I do so I can build app.js/main.js at the same time, and have it usable with Express?

### Edit

When I built app.js by itself, I just commented out [line 38 here](http://pastebin.com/p5isXwSd). I tried swapping lines 38/39 to see if order matters and now my webpack build fails with this:

```
> webpack --progress --colors --watch --inline --config webpack/development.js

 69% 1332/1350 builHash: 194ece3ebdbb1574a343
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 10287ms
 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.js  9.62 MB       0  [emitted]  app
   [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1209 hidden modules

WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependencies:
78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56
Hash: 849be51dfde2a0e34a2b  
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 15130ms
                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
ed19359cb473909255e502db33bd7f63.png    1.51 MB          [emitted]  
e1ea82cb1c39656b925012efe60f22ea.png    11.5 kB          [emitted]  
        main.849be51dfde2a0e34a2b.js    13.1 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                          index.html  531 bytes          [emitted]  
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1374 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/sntp/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dgram' in /project/node_modules/sntp/lib
 @ ./~/sntp/lib/index.js 3:12-28

ERROR in ./~/sntp/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dns' in /project/node_modules/sntp/lib
 @ ./~/sntp/lib/index.js 4:10-24
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 1 hidden modules
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the webpack multi-compiler works. I just want each entry point to be built totally separately. I thought by using an array like this I could save myself the pain of running `webpack --watch frontend.dev.js` `webpack --watch backend.dev.js` in two terminals.

Comment: webpack is not meant to be used in node environments. `__webpack_require__` reaches out to `window` for some of it's functionality (which obviously does not exist in node)

Comment: If I run webpack multiple times to build app.js/main.js using this same config but without the multi-compiler feature, both are built correctly. Node happily runs app.js and serves main.js with my webapp in it. I needed to add `target: 'node'` to make it run with Node.